# Downloading multiple instances of one image from a website and saving them in a Windows folder

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to download multiple images from thispersondoesnotexist.com and save them in a Windows folder. The site uses an AI StyleGAN to generate thousands of face images, but the problem is that the site only generates one image per view, which is labelled as image.jpg, and this single image changes every time the page is reset.

I would like to write a Python script that retrieves and saves multiple instances of this randomly generated image, ending up with a number of different images.

I tried using the following script written by Nandhugp:

```
import urllib.request
import random


n=input("How many images do you need?")
val=int(n)
dir=input("Enter the directory you want to save")
for i in range(val):
   file_name = random.randrange(1,10000)
   full_file_name = dir + str(file_name) + '.jpg' #Insert your
   def downloader(image_url,full_file_name):


     urllib.request.urlretrieve(image_url,full_file_name)

   downloader("https://www.thispersondoesnotexist.com/",full_file_name)
```

However, the script doesn't work for me; I'm sorry but I'm new to Python 3 and am also having some difficulty understanding file paths in Windows. When the script asks for the directory I want to save the files in, do I enter "c:\faces\" or "c:/faces/"?

I'm using Win 7 64-bit OS on an older laptop.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the
[ask] link for more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.What did you try?

Comment: You need use `https://thispersondoesnotexist.com/image`

Comment: I used https://thispersondoesnotexist.com/image as you suggested but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# python3
import requests
def download(fileName):
    f = open(fileName,'wb')
    f.write(requests.get('https://thispersondoesnotexist.com/image', headers={'User-Agent': 'My User Agent 1.0'}).content)
    f.close()

for i in range(2000):
    download(str(i)+'.jpg')
```

```
//node js
var request = require('request');

var fs = require('fs');
var sleep = function (duration) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve(), duration)
    });
}
var downloadFile = function (url, fileName) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        var req = request(url);
        var file = fs.createWriteStream(fileName);
        req.pipe(file);
        req.on('end', () => {
            resolve();
        })
    })
}
var main = async function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        console.log('Downloading ' + i)
        await downloadFile('https://thispersondoesnotexist.com/image', `${i}.jpg`)
        await sleep(1000);
    }
}

main();
```

---

Comment: Thank you for these, but I'm using Python 3 for the script I posted, and it's not working

Comment: On my side, `node` is working, and with python, the image is destroyed, but some image can download, python version is not important

Comment: I updated my answer with python3 version, in my case, `headers={'User-Agent': 'My User Agent 1.0'}` is important with that url.

Comment: Hurrah! node is indeed working ... all I needed to do was create an "img" folder where the images are saved -- this is all I really needed, thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you were using Linux or Cygwin on Windows, you could just run this:

```
watch -n6 wget https://thispersondoesnotexist.com/image
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: My response does not require documentation or citations:- it is simple and concise, and I have tested it in a real world compute environment.

Comment: The documentation for both 'watch' and 'wget' are available on almost all Linux systems via the system manpages or if you have no access to them they are available here - though these are probably system specific!: https://linux.die.net/man/